# How fix a element to bottom

Tags: java, android, xml, admob

I've a layout with `ScrollView`, `LinearLayout` *(for the device with small screen)* but when i put my `AD` **i don't see it in my screen**. And in the `layout` *(from Android Studio)*, i didn't see my `AD` in device screen.

Can you help me to try resolve it ?

Thanks :)

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin">

    <!-- Login progress -->

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/login_form"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/email_login_form"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <AutoCompleteTextView
                    android:id="@+id/id"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:elevation="1dp"
                    android:hint="@string/connect_id"
                    android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
                    android:maxLines="1"
                    android:singleLine="true" />

            </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

            <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/connectbutton"
                style="?android:textAppearanceSmall"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                android:text="@string/connect_button"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:paddingTop="15dp"
                android:text="@string/connect_tutorial_id_title"
                android:textSize="24sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView2"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/connect_tutorial_id_content" />


        </LinearLayout>


    </ScrollView>

    <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/adViewLandingPage"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="39dp"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:gravity="bottom"
        ads:adSize="BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="@string/pub_connect" />

</LinearLayout>
```

I didn't think it's my Java code :

```
  mAdView = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.adViewLandingPage);
        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
                .addTestDevice("XX")
                .build();
        mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your ScrollView has:

```
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
```

which is covering your ad. To fix this, change your ScrollView tag to look like this:

```
 <ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/login_form"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1">
```

Comment: Thank's :) But what is ` android:layout_height="0"` because i have an error for the 0

Comment: Try it as 1 (not "1"), without the quotes.

Comment: When you said you "have an error for the 0", what did you mean? What is the error?

Comment: MY MISTAKE!! Set the height to "0dp"

Comment: I have allready try this but that's didn't show. I have found an other error from my XML AD `android:layout_height="39dp"`. Thank's for your help :) You save me ! :)